# MailChimp, Modal, Foundry

Tags: modal-dialog, mailchimp, rapidweaver

Greetings: I'm trying to troubleshoot why the embed code for MailChimp is not working when users click SUBSCRIBE. Here's the link to the site, where I added a "Newsletter 2" to show this, and the original Newsletter button that uses a "mailto:" code, which is not optimal since it does not work with MailChimp to collect email addresses from users.

Here's the code from MailChimp. Any help is appreciated...THANK YOU!

Using Rapidweaver with Foundry theme and HTML stack to embed the code. Website being used: [https://metrospeechlanguagenetwork.org][1]

```html
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://metrospeechlanguagenetwork.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=2be85436fc7ceacf1e36f4a2f&amp;id=dd495cf964" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <h2>Subscribe</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_2be85436fc7ceacf1e36f4a2f_dd495cf964" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->


<script type="text/javascript">
  function form_submit() {
    document.getElementById("search_form").submit();
   }    
  function form_reset() {
    document.getElementById("search_form").reset();
   }  
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joel Solomon
Your real script need to be in the Copy/Paste textarea in Mailchimp.com site, right bellow the form you has write.
It is in the form of:

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {
window.fnames = new Array(); 
window.ftypes = new Array();
fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';
fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';
fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';
fnames[3]='ADDRESS';ftypes[3]='address';
fnames[4]='PHONE';ftypes[4]='phone';
fnames[5]='BIRTHDAY';ftypes[5]='birthday';
}(jQuery));
var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```